# Reading text from Docx File using Docx4j

Tags: java, ms-word, docx4j

Hi I am trying to read data from one Docx file using Docx4j, so I can insert it into another file. My code is as follows:

```
public void getTextFromOtherFile() throws Docx4JException, JAXBException {
    File doc = new File("D:\\helloWorld.docx");
    WordprocessingMLPackage wordMLPackage = WordprocessingMLPackage.load(doc);
    MainDocumentPart mainDocumentPart = wordMLPackage.getMainDocumentPart();
    System.out.println(mainDocumentPart.getXML());
}
```

The code works fine. But as soon as I insert following line in the end of above stated method, the method started generating exception:

```
List<Object> jAXBNodesViaXPath = mainDocumentPart.getJAXBNodesViaXPath("//w:t", true);
```

The exception which I am facing is as follows:

```
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [jsp] in context with path [/osses] threw exception [javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.xml.utils.DefaultErrorHandler.<init>(Z)V] with root cause
```

java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.xml.utils.DefaultErrorHandler.(Z)V
    at org.docx4j.org.apache.xalan.transformer.TransformerIdentityImpl.(TransformerIdentityImpl.java:1459)
    at org.docx4j.org.apache.xalan.transformer.TransformerIdentityImpl.(TransformerIdentityImpl.java:96)
    at org.docx4j.utils.XmlSerializerUtil.serialize(XmlSerializerUtil.java:18)
    at org.docx4j.XmlUtils.w3CDomNodeToString(XmlUtils.java:833)
    at org.docx4j.XmlUtils.xpath(XmlUtils.java:1206)
    at org.docx4j.XmlUtils.xpath(XmlUtils.java:1200)
    at org.docx4j.XmlUtils.getJAXBAssociationsForXPath(XmlUtils.java:1191)
    at org.docx4j.XmlUtils.getJAXBNodesViaXPath(XmlUtils.java:1133)
    at org.docx4j.openpackaging.parts.JaxbXmlPartXPathAware.getJAXBNodesViaXPath(JaxbXmlPartXPathAware.java:190)
    at Business.SelectionBean.getTextFromOtherFile(SelectionBean.java:1087)
    at org.apache.jsp.test_jsp._jspService(test_jsp.java:95)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:439)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:395)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:339)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at Business.NoCacheFilter.doFilter(NoCacheFilter.java:36)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:219)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:110)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:506)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:169)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:962)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:445)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1115)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:637)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:318)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

My word file contains two lines which are as follows:
Hello My name is abcd.
I love my work.
I am stuck at this point from previous 7 days but unable to resolve this problem. I also included different jar files (Xalan, xml-apis-1.3.04, serializer-2.7.2) but no luck. I am using docx4j-6.0.1.jar for my work. 
Can anybody please guide me for this problem. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Works for me (docx4j 6.0.1, Xalan 2.7.2, serializer 2.7.2)

I guess your classpath doesn't contain the jars you think it does.

org.apache.xml.utils.DefaultErrorHandler is in Xalan 2.7.2.

Also, the line numbers in your stack trace:

```
    java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.xml.utils.DefaultErrorHandler.(Z)V 
at org.docx4j.org.apache.xalan.transformer.TransformerIdentityImpl.(TransformerIdentityImpl.java:1459) 
at org.docx4j.org.apache.xalan.transformer.TransformerIdentityImpl.(TransformerIdentityImpl.java:96)
```

don't match the docx4j source code, so that's strange.